# Export contacts from Gmail Business account to a different Gmail Personal account

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, google-apps-email

My business uses Gmail client for email, and has a saved list of all the contacts within the company.  Whenever you begin to type a name in the "To:" field, it will automatically match members who are already in the company.

I would like the same contact functionally in my personal email, but when I tried to export the contacts in a CSV from my business email, the CSV contains only the contacts for which I've directly sent emails to in the past.

Is there anyway to migrate all the business contacts to my personal account?

Comment: Go to GMail, switch to contacts, "Other Contacts" select everything and add to the group "My Contacts", then they will be available in the CSV

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can migrate all of the contacts.

Go to your business gmail account and select contacts on the sidebar

[image]

Click on the arrow next to the checkbox and select "All"

[image]

Then go to "More" and select export.

[image]

This will bring up a pop-up that will look like the image below. Select the options selected below and hit "Export..."

[image]

This should start a download of a .csv file.

Now, sign out of your business account and into your personal one. Go to the same contacts page, click more and this time, click "Import..."

Click choose file and browse for the .csv file. Click import and the contacts will be imported. There may be some duplicates so go once more to "More" and click "Find & merge duplicates..."

Hope that this helps!